# Create XSLT from Schema (XSD) files

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I want to create XSLT files from XSD files for transforming XML files to be valid (against XSD). I have 12 XSD files and more than a thousand XML files using them. If I make a change to XSD files I need to change all XML files to be valid, which is impossible to be done manually. I guess the native way to do this is by using XSLT transformations. and I need XSLT to do the transformation.

Comment: My main problem is the order of elements. It would be enough for me if the XSLT transformation just corrects the order of elements.

Comment: You brought upon yourself the wrath of the XSLT folks :)… Too late for me to answer, but I must comment… I think you’re talking about a common problem, which is how to maintain data in XML files when XSDs change (e.g. rename a tag, remove content, move content around, etc.). To solve it, you have to think that XML is data already “presented”. The way I did it was to move the data from XML into another layer (e.g. spreadsheets that are organized to capture what the data is about) and from there use an XML builder to generate whatever XML you need, on demand.

Comment: (cont'd) I actually ended up building a whole solution for it, so if you want to try it, contact me directly through the support email on my website and we'll take it from there.

Comment: I guess, this question does not deserve -3 points, as it is a common problem. I understand that there is no simple solution for this, so I can spend time coding scripts for transforming the XML files.

Comment: This is a common problem, I am working on a solution and I would like to share, if question were not closed. Question is clear enough.

Comment: I suggest you post a question on meta (see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144209/what-happened-to-xsd) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144213/reverse-synonymization-of-xsd-and-xml-schema-tags)); please read both since the first one was closed: all you need to do is provide a brief explanation regarding the commonality of the problem and a real life example which should help people relate to the issue at hand. I totally agree that these people rushed into closing your question without thinking too much about the question. I see your scenario every day.

Comment: (cont'd)... the question should ask the re-opening of your question; use the `reopen-closed` tag, and look for other questions tagged the same to prepare your question better.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not well-specified. For example if your schema requires a single element foo containing an integer, and your instance document contains the structure

```
<body>
  <x>London</x>
  <y>Paris</y>
</body>
```

then what would you expect the transformation to do?

Comment: My main problem is the order of elements. It would be enough for me if the XSLT transformation just corrects the order of elements. I sometimes need to add elements to XML files using PHP. But element is added at bottom, and all XML files become invalid.

Comment: I guess problem is specified well enough. As in the explanation, XML files are allready generated from 12 XSD files, they are not artbitrary XML files.

Comment: This is a common problem, I am working on a solution and I would like to share, if question were not closed. Question is clear enough.

Comment: If you think the question is clear, then please comment on my example, which was designed to show that it is very far from clear.

Comment: I can't speak for the original poster, but if the problem is (as some later comments seem to suggest) generating XSLT to move valid XML instances from version N of a schema to version N+1, then I would expect such problems to be rare.  In the context of a tool to take a body of invalid input and generate valid output, I think it is worth thinking about what kinds of problems can be autocorrected and what cannot.  (On the other hand, I don't know any tools to do either of these, so my only answer to the OP's question, if it's meant either of those ways, is "Good luck.")

Comment: Yes, there's certainly an interesting problem there: there must be a class of (v1, v2) schema-pairs where generating a transformation from instances of v1 to instances of v2 can be automated, with some hope of making reasonable assumptions about the requirements. The OP's problem of changing the order of child elements might fall into that class. But a somewhat wider class would be those transformations that can be easily expressed using the visual mapping tools in products like XML Spy and Stylus Studio, and perhaps that's the way the OP should go.

Comment: thanks for comments. I ended up in coding a Java Program to correct order of elements. It Reads Rules from XSD and inputs XML file and outputs corrected XML file. It works for me. It may also output XSLT, but not necessary right now, as correction is done by program.